# Vector Iterator not Incrementable In for loop

Tags: c++, vector

Alright so I know people have gone on and on about this topic, but I've searched question after question and edited my code repeatedly, and I still seem to be having this problem.
This piece of code is basically intended to run through a vector and compare/combine its contents. In order to do that, I use 'it' and 'in' to go through the vector and .erase to delete contents that have been combined into new parts of the vector. Knowing I would basically need the .erase function and iterators, I used some code (the auto it stuff) from other questions on StackOverflow that seemed to work in this situation. Since I'm unfamiliar with that code, I may have used it incorrectly for this situation, though I'm not sure about that.

Anyway, as the title indicates, I'm getting a 'vector iterator not incrementable' error. The program seems to be running into this error after going through the second for loop a few times. I've tried a lot of things, but I just can't seem to figure out what part of my code is the real problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\if (!strvector.empty()) {
        for (auto in = strvector.begin(); in != strvector.end() - 1;) {//in order to process if there is more than one final piece

            str = ' ' + *in + ' ';//adds spaces so it only compares beginnings & ends
            if (strvector.size() < 2) {
                break;
            }//doesn't do anything if there are too few objects to process

            for (auto it = strvector.begin(); it != strvector.end() - 1;) { 
                if (strvector.size() < 2) {
                    break;
                }//doesn't continue if there are too few objects to process
                str2 = ' ' + *it + ' '; //adds spaces so it only compares beginnings & ends
                substr = str; //sets substring of string to be chopped up
                while (substr.length() >= 6) { //only processes substrings >= 6 characters bc smaller bits are useless
                    size_t found = str2.find(substr); //searches str2 for substr
                    if (found != string::npos) {
                        str = str.substr(0, substr.length()) + ' '; //cuts substr off of str
                        str.append(str2); //adds str and str2
                        it = strvector.erase(it);
                        substr = 'a'; //shortens substr to get out of while
                        test=1;
                    }//end if
                    else {
                        substr.erase(substr.size() - 1, 1); //if substr was not found, decrement substr and compare again
                    }
                }//end while

                substr = str; //resets substr
                while (substr.length() >= 6) { //only processes substrings >= 6 characters bc smaller bits are useless
                    size_t found = str2.find(substr); //searches str2 for substr
                    if (found != string::npos) {
                        str = str.substr(substr.length()) + ' '; //cuts substr from beginning of string
                        str = str2 + str; //adds str2 and str, with str2 at the beginning
                        it = strvector.erase(it++);
                        substr = 'a'; //shortens substr to get out of while 
                        test=1;

                    }//end if
                    else {
                        substr.erase(0, 1); //erases the first character of the string
                    }
                    if (test < 1) {
                        it++; //increments if the erase function did not already do that
                    }

                }//end while
                if (test != 1) {
                    it++; //increments if the erase function did not already do that
                }
                if (test < 2) {
                    strvector.push_back(str); //adds new str to the vector
                    test = 0;
                }
            }//end ptr2 for
            if (strvector.size() < 2) {
                in = strvector.erase(in - 1);
            }
            else {
                in++;
            }
            cout << "str1 is " << str << endl; //prints out str
        }//end ptr for
    }//end if vector is not empty
```

Comment: `it = strvector.erase(it++);` just looks wrong, without analysing it to know if it is wrong.

Comment: You can't iterate through a container and modify it at the same time.

Comment: Erasing an entry from the `vector` is invalidating the iterator for the next pass!

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `erase` on a `std::vector` the iterator that you're using becomes invalid.  Instead the call to `erase` returns a brand new iterator that you should use going forward.

In your case, you're using the postfix ++ operator which will attempt to increment the iterator after it has been used by the `erase` method.  At that point the iterator is invalid and so you get an error.

What you likely want is `it = strvector.erase(it);` which removes the element at the iterator and then returns a new iterator positioned at the element after the one you erased.  You don't need the additional `++` because `erase` effectively did that for you.

Comment: I made that edit, but I'm still getting the error. Thank you for the suggestion thought.